# Read folder/file name, search on the internet and automatically save related picture

Tags: vbscript, scripting, automation

According to [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), which states

> - if you have a question that you already know the answer to
> - if you’d like to document it in public so others (including yourself) can find it later
> - it is OK to ask, and answer, your own question on a relevant Stack Exchange site.
>
> **To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged**

I'm putting it here for research purpouses, but if anyone is willing to convert it to JavaScript (maybe `node.js`?), that would be greatly appreciated.

---

I have this `VBScript` in my `SendTo` folder, so i can click on any movie folder or file and search it on [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/) and [RotenTomatoes](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/), and automatically save the movie poster as `folder.jpg`.

Enjoy.

PS: use a `CScript` shortcut to execute it, otherwise you will end up with a lot of "alerts" (due to `WScript.Echo`)

Comment: Why the (almost) unnecessary explanation? Because i just got my previous attempt put on hold. The reason? `This is not a question. SO isn't the right place for showcasing your work. Use a blog for that.` Nice... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim objVideo, objRegEx
DebugMode = False
objFile = Wscript.Arguments(0)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    objVideo = objFSO.GetBaseName(objFile)
    ImageFile = "folder.jpg"
    VideoYearParenteses = ""
    DestFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile) & "\"
    If objFSO.FolderExists(objFile) Then DestFolder = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(objFile) & "\"

Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegEx.Global = True
    objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True

    objRegEx.Pattern = "((19|20)\d\d)"
    Set VideoYearMatches = objRegEx.Execute(objVideo)
    If VideoYearMatches.count > 0 Then
        VideoYear = Trim(VideoYearMatches.item(0))
        VideoYearParenteses = "+(" & VideoYear & ")"
    End If

    objRegEx.Pattern = "\W?((19|20)\d\d|(720|1080)(i|p)).*"
    VideoTitle = objRegEx.Replace(objVideo, "")
    VideoTitle = Trim(VideoTitle)

    objRegEx.Pattern = "(\s|\.|_)"
    VideoTitleEncoded = objRegEx.Replace(VideoTitle, "+")
    VideoTitleEncoded = Trim(VideoTitleEncoded)

If DebugMode Then WScript.Echo "Nome original: " & objVideo & vbCrlf & "VideoTitle: " & VideoTitle & vbCrlf & "VideoTitleEncoded: " & VideoTitleEncoded & vbCrlf & "VideoYear: " & VideoYear

' OPEN WITH CHROME? IS THERE A CHROME OBJECT TO MANIPULATE?
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
    'wshShell.Run "chrome.exe http://www.imdb.com/search/title?title=" & VideoTitleEncoded & "&release_date=" & VideoYear & "&title_type=feature"
    'wshShell.Run "chrome.exe http://www.imdb.com/find?s=tt&exact=true&q=" & VideoTitleEncoded & VideoYearParenteses
    'wshShell.Run "chrome.exe http://www.rottentomatoes.com/search/?search=" & VideoTitleEncoded & VideoYearParenteses


' INTERNET EXPLORER OBJECT AND DOM MANIPULATION
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Navigate "http://www.imdb.com/search/title?title=" & VideoTitleEncoded & "&release_date=" & VideoYear & "&title_type=feature"
    If DebugMode Then ie.Visible = True

Do While ie.Busy
    WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

imgThumb = ie.document.getElementById("main").getElementsByTagName("img").item(0).src
WScript.Echo("Caminho da imagem pequena: " & imgThumb)

Call Principal

Sub Principal
    Set regEx = New RegExp
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "\._.*(?=\.)"
    End With
    imgNormal = regEx.Replace(imgThumb, "")

    WScript.Echo("Caminho da imagem grande: " & imgNormal)

    If DebugMode Then ie.Navigate imgNormal

    Set xml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        xml.Open "GET", imgNormal, False
        xml.Send

    Set oStream = createobject("Adodb.Stream")
    Const adTypeBinary = 1
    Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
    Const adSaveCreateNotExist = 1 

    oStream.type = adTypeBinary
    oStream.open
    oStream.write xml.responseBody

    'oStream.savetofile DestFolder & ImageFile, adSaveCreateNotExist
    oStream.savetofile DestFolder & ImageFile, adSaveCreateOverWrite

    WScript.Echo(vbCrLf & "Imagem salva em " & DestFolder & ImageFile)
    oStream.close

    set oStream = nothing
    Set xml = Nothing

    WScript.Echo(vbCrLf & "Fim!")
End Sub
```